# Ensure a batch file is called with given arguments at most N times

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, find

I have a Windows batch file that receives several arguments, and performs some tasks on files.

My main purpose is to execute a certain task (the batch file with a given set of arguments) at most 5 times. In order to do this, I redirected its outputs (and echoed the calling arguments) to a `log.file`.

I want to check if the same command has been issued before, so I do a find:

```
.....

set retryC=0
@set cc=%*
:: replace quote with double quote so it works with find
@set cc=%cc:"=""%
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=3" %%f in ('find /C "%cc%" "d:\temp\log.file"') do set retryC=%%f
@echo retry count = %retryC%
@echo local retry count = !retryC!
endlocal
```

This will only echo a zero result in the log file no matter how many times it's executed.

```
retry count = 0
local retry count = 0
```

However, if I copy the line that's being output in the log by the `for` command, and execute it directly in the console, it works

```
>for /F "tokens=3" %f in ('find /C "-p1 ""p1val"" -p2 ""p2val""" "d:\temp\log.file"') do set retryC=%f
>set retryC=14
```

Any ideas why this happens and how I can get the same result inside the batch file?

I already tried to perform a `copy /v /y "d:\temp\log.file" "d:\temp\tmp.file"` before the find, and perform the `for` on it, with the same (zero) result

Comment: Try to expand the value of `cc` with exclamation marks instead percents: `('find /C "!cc!" "d:\temp\log.file"') `

Comment: I tried, it didn't help. In this case, the command expanded in the log to `for /F "tokens=3" %f in ('find /C "!cc!" "d:\temp\log.file"') do set retryC=%f`